# Using spyder IDE on OSX - DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable not available within spyder

Tags: macos, psycopg2, anaconda, spyder

I'm using Spyder as an IDE (on OSX Mavericks) for a project and I need to connect to a Postgres database. So I'm using the psycopg2 package.

When I initially ran python by itself in the terminal it wouldn't run because I hadn't DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set. To fix that I added DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib to ~/.bashrc and then sourced ~/.bashrc.

That fixes it when I open terminal, run python and import psycopg2 - perfect!

But when I open Spyder through the launcher app, it doesn't appear to have access to the DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH environment variable, so I can't import psycopg2. Is there any way to ensure python sessions in spyder use the same environment variables?

So far I've tried

1. Adding DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib to ~/.bashrc
   ~./profile and ~/.bash_profile but this doesn't seem to work for the
   Spyder session (it works when running python from terminal)
2. Creating ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist and adding DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH.
   This didn't seem to do anything. (if I did it correctly... after
   doing this do I need to source environment.plist or anything to
   activate?)
3. In a Spyder session importing os and running os.environ['DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH']='/Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib. DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH then seems to be in os.environ but it still doesn't seem to work.
4. Creating a launchd.conf file with setenv DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH /Library/PostgreSQL/9.3/lib'. I'm not sure I did this correctly though as when I rebooted my computer wouldn't turn on and I had to go into recovery mode to delete launchd.conf. (Could anyone give an example of how this file should look?)
5. Running spyder directly from terminal instead of the launcher. But that's a whole different kettle of fish, it said I don't have PyQT4.6+ (but I do!!)

Does anyone know how to get spyder to acknowledge DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH?